Why does power of power yield different results
$2^{(2x+1)^{0.5}}=32$ or $2^{\sqrt{(2x+1)}}=32$?
Scenario 1

$2^{(2x+1)^{0.5}}=2^5$.
$2^{0.5(2x+1)}=2^5$ (power of power rule)
$\log2^{0.5(2x+1)}=\log2^5$ (log both sides, pull the exponents out front, & then algebra)
$0.5(2x+1)=5$
$(1x+0.5)=5$
$x=5-0.5$
$x=4.5$
Checking $2^{0.5(2(4.5)+1)}=2^5$
$2^{0.5(9+1)}=2^5$
$2^{0.5(10)}=2^5$
$2^{5}=2^5$

Scenario 2

$2^{(2x+1)^{0.5}}=32$
$2^{(2x+1)^{0.5}}=2^5$
$(2x+1)^{0.5}=5$
$((2x+1)^{0.5})^2=5^2$
$2x+1=25$
$2x=25-1$
$2x=24$
$x=24×2^{-1}$
$x=12$
Checking $2^{(2(12)+1)^{0.5}}=2^5$
$2^{(24+1)^{0.5}}=2^5$
$2^{(25)^{0.5}}=2^5$
$2^5=2^5$

Why are there 2 solutions?! Shouldn't the power of power rule yield the same results?

In scenario 1, you have invalid checking.  You should check against the original expression.  This is to catch what happened: you used the power of power rule incorrectly.  The rule you used applies to $(a^b)^c$, so that $b$ and $c$ are the "same height" above the baseline.  The expression you have is $a^{(b^c)}$, which is not the same thing.

You interpret the meaning of the term
$$2^{(2x+1)^{0.5}}$$
differently in both scenarios.
In the first scenario you interpret it as (using brackets to make the meaning clear)
$$\left[2^{(2x+1)}\right]^{0.5}.$$
In the second scenario you iterpret it as
$$2^\left[{(2x+1)}^{0.5}\right].$$
In both cases you do 2 exponantions, but the order you do them in is different.
Unlike addition and multiplication, the order of doing the operations does  matter!
To use a simple example $(2^3)^4 = 8^4 = 4096 = 2^{12} < 2^{81} = 2^{(3^4)}$.
As often, mathematics has used conventions to clarify what $a^{b^c}$ is supposed to mean when encountered. And that convention is that $a^{b^c} := a^{\left(b^c\right)}$, so your second scenario is the correct interpretation.

So when I see a long chain of exponentiation there's implied brackets at each interval? Otherwise how do you tell if a term has a different "height" & is there a different rule for those ones?

Yes, each "tower" of exponents without explicite parenthesese means you start calculating it "from the top". Something like $e^{x^2}$ is relatively common, maybe one more exponent happens from time to time. Any more seems not to come up except in a "natural" way.

If I were to have $$32^5$$ & I reduce it $$(2^5)^5$$ then $$2^{25}$$ because they're equal height & then the power of power rule can be applied?

Yes. The "power of power" rule means you can simplify $(a^b)^c$ to $a^{bc}$. I'd like to emphasize that the important part is the order of operations (a.k.a how are the parenthesis set, or how would they be set to demonstarte the order of operations), which is a mathematical property of the calculation. At which height the exponents are shown is a question of typsetting and more a question of convention. In your $$ (2^5)^5$$ example, MathJax puts both $5$'s at the same level, but if it would keep the parenthesese but put the second $5$ higher, it wouldn't change the value of the expression.
